# Right click using keyboard in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, right-click

How can I do a right-click using the keyboard in [Mac OS X Snow Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) using the Logitech Wave Keyboard?

The keyboard has keys as <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, but it only works in Windows, not Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From "[How can the mouse pointer be moved using the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/93584/move-cursor-using-keyboard)":

Search for “mouse keys” in System Preferences. Enabling it (which can usually be done by tapping Option five times) allows the numeric keypad to function as an 8-direction “joystick” (<kbd>7</kbd> = left+up, <kbd>8</kbd> = up, <kbd>9</kbd> = right+up, etc.). Use the keypad's <kbd>5</kbd> to click the mouse (press it twice, quickly to double click; hold <kbd>Control</kbd> while pressing to right-click).

Comment: and on a macbook ?