# Keyboard shortcut for spelling dropdown menu in OS X beyond Devonthink Pro?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, textmate, spell-check

Similar to this question: [Keyboard Shortcut to Right Click in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/93937/keyboard-shortcut-to-right-click-in-mac-os-x) , I'm trying to find more efficient ways to use spell check in OS X. I've discovered that Devonthink Pro will, if you hit "command-period" (that's "."), give you a dropdown menu with potential fixes. Textmate and MS Word won't do this, so I assume it's a feature unique to Devonthink Pro.

Does anyone know if this is true? Alternately, is there a way to do something similar in Word 2008?

Comment: Your tags don't make sense, you talk about DT Pro but tagged TextMate?

Comment: You may want to try asking this question at apple.stackexchange.com as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is not spelling correction, but auto-completion. Press `[esc]` in TextEdit, TextMate and pretty much any sane application. I don't know about Word.