# Can I map an MacBook or Apple keyboard key combo to act like a Windows menu key?

Tags: windows, macbook, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Shortcut to Right Click in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/93937/keyboard-shortcut-to-right-click-in-mac-os-x)

In Windows, the Menu Key (or Context-Menu Key — to the right of the space bar) allows you to right-click the currently selected text or graphic object, but without using the mouse. I like the feature in Windows and miss it when I'm back on my Mac. I would like to find a utility or a method that lets me assign this behaviour to a key or key combination on my Apple keyboard. 

 Anybody know how?

Comment: Answered here:

[Keyboard Shortcut to Right Click in Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/93937/keyboard-shortcut-to-right-click-in-mac-os-x)